# How create css semi donut menu

Tags: css, html

i'm try create semi donut menu by css same [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3shtr.jpg)

But I've found was it was written with SVG,i do not know about SVG, i'm looking for by CSS. Thanks.

Comment: This website is not for posting programming goals and experiences.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly acknowledge, ideally you would use SVG, and I recommend downloading Inkscape and producing the menu there and then simply embedding the SVG.

With that said, it can be done with pure CSS using transforms. Here's a good tutorial: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/